# Make .val() trigger each time a new value appears then update a data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make .val() trigger each time a new value appears then update a data attribute in a button

I can get the number from:

```
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="100">
```

Using:

$("input#quantity").val();

Now I want this to be triggered every time the .val() HTML value changes.

I have a plus and minus arrow which can update the HTML value, the full mark up is as follows:

```
<form class="cart-num" action="index.html" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="100">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">
              </span>
         </button>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
     </button>
</span>
```

Each time the above is fired I need to update the data-quantity in the following code:

```
<a data-quantity="3" data-product_id="<?php echo $product->get_id() ?>" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_variable">Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: Hook an `input` event handler to the `input`, and update the `a` element as needed

Comment: lookup the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated the plus/minus functionality so you might just ignore that part, but this should work as expected (and I also don't check for negative quantity for simplicity reason):

```js
$(function(){
 $('span.glyphicon').on('click', function(){
     if($(this).hasClass('glyphicon-minus')){
         $('input#quantity').val(parseInt($('input#quantity').val()) - 1);
        } else {
         $('input#quantity').val(parseInt($('input#quantity').val()) + 1);
        }
        $('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', $('input#quantity').val());
        logDataQuantityAttribute();
    });

 $('input#quantity').on('keyup', function(){
  $('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity', this.value);
        logDataQuantityAttribute();
 });
});

function logDataQuantityAttribute(){
 console.log('data-quantity Attribute: ' + $('a.add_to_cart_variable').attr('data-quantity'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="100">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">MINUS</span>
         </button>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">PLUS</span>
     </button>
</span>

<a data-quantity="1" data-product_id="123456789" class="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_variable">Add to cart</a>
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wrote in my text ... I guess the plus/minus buttons are already working? I just did this for demonstration purpose.

Comment: Ah - my bad, didn't see that you mentioned this in your answer :-)

Comment: Amazing! The only issue now is there is more than one 'glyphicon-minus' etc on the page so the $('span.glyphicon').on('click', is not firing properly. Is there anyway round this?

And thanks!

Comment: Amazing! The only issue now is there is more than one 'glyphicon-minus' etc on the page so the $('span.glyphicon').on('click', is not firing properly. Is there anyway round this?

And thanks!

Comment: Sure, replace this $('span.glyphicon') for example with $('button.btn-number').find('span.glyphicon') so it'll look for a button with a class "btn-number" and then find the <span> in it. You can modify the selector as you like.

Answer (score 0):

To detect input value  change you can use

```
$("#quantity").on("change paste keyup", function() {
      alert($(this).val()); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I completed your requirement. You need to update the attribute whenever you want to change the value of text box. Also you want to change the value and attribute when you click "-" & "+" button. This code will work for all your scenario.

```js
$(function(){
$("#update_tag").attr("data-update-val",$("#quantity").val());
$("#quantity").on("change",function(){
$("#update_tag").attr("data-update-val",$("#quantity").val());
});

$(".quantity-left-minus").on("click",function(){
if($("#quantity").val()<2)
return false;
 $("#quantity").val($("#quantity").val()-1);
 $("#update_tag").attr("data-update-val",$("#quantity").val());
});

$(".quantity-right-plus").on("click",function(){
 $("#quantity").val(+$("#quantity").val()+1);
 $("#update_tag").attr("data-update-val",$("#quantity").val());
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="100">
     <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button type="button" class="quantity-left-minus btn btn-number"  data-type="minus" data-field="">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus">-
              </span>
         </button>
            </span>
            <span class="input-group-btn">
           <button type="button" class="quantity-right-plus btn btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="">
           
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">+</span>
     </button>
     <a href="#" data-update-val="1" id="update_tag">add</a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('form.cart-num button').on('click',function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $quantity = $this.closest('form').find('input[name=quantity]'),
        $addToCart = $('a.ajax_add_to_cart');
        newQuantity = parseInt( $quantity.val() ) + ( $this.hasClass('quantity-left-minus') ? -1 : 1 );
    if( newQuantity < 1 ){
      newQuantity = 1;
    }
    $quantity.val( newQuantity );
    $addToCart.attr('data-quantity', newQuantity )
  });
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jamespoel/pen/zzjrqE

Comment: Note; this doesn't take into account the user editing the input field directly. You'll have to bind to the **keyup** event on the input field if you want that.